# Jquery alert hello Plugin doesnt work

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make  simple Jquery plugin. I went through the Jquery documention and I reduced the layout to make a simple alert. This is my Jquery Plugin code.

```
        (function($){
      $.fn.foo = function(){
        alert("HI");
      };


})(jQuery);
```

Than on my main page I have the Jquery reference URL and this code

```
  <script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  foo();
    });
</script>
```

I keep getting errors in the debugger
SCRIPT5009: 'foo' is undefined

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can invoke the foo method on some element or need to define it differently e.g.

```
<div id="test" />
```

Plugin -

```
(function($){
      $.fn.foo = function(){
        alert("HI");
      };

       $.otherfoo = function(){
            alert('Hiiiii');
        };
})(jQuery);
```

Test -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').foo();
  $.otherfoo();  
});
```

should work fine.

Comment: Nope. It needs to be defined differently. I edited the answer to demo both.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [widget factory](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#The_widget_factory), it makes writing jQuery plugins much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You made a jquery plugin, you have to reference it in seperate jQuery function to fire it.

Here is my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/Z9vz2/